# DrawText seems to cause memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, directx-9

I have a function which displays some text on screen

```
void DisplayText()
{
    RECT rct;
    rct.left = 250;
    rct.right = 500;
    rct.top = 150;
    rct.bottom = 400;
    titleFont->DrawText(NULL,L"Hello world" , -1, &rct, DT_CENTER, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 255, 255));
}
```

`titleFont` is of `LPD3DXFONT`.

If I run application with above code, its memory usage keeps on increasing (I think it is memory leak)

However,If I comment just one line from code which contains call to `DrawText`, keeping remaining code as it is. Its memory usage remains constant. (no memory leak)

What could be causing this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run a profiler tool to confirm the memory leak? It's possible there's a leak here, but I'd be very surprised if that really was the case.

Comment: Please explain, how do I run a profiler tool and test it? I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with how to do this in Windows (I typically develop in Linux), but this older question might have some advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: @Talha5389, try Deleaker, but don't forget to disable filters. Make a snapshot before calling DrawText and the second snapshot after the call. Then just compare them.